# Whether credit report includes length of employment or pay check details?

Tags: united-states, loans, credit-score

Whether credit report includes length of employment (or) pay check  details to the Financial Institute which is running credit check on an Individual?

In order to provide Loan, Does the period of employment or pay check details are visible to the Financial Institutes?

Comment: No, but when you apply for a loan, the lender typically asks for this information (and proof of it).

Comment: Yes .. But we generally provide details to the max of about last 6 months.. My concern was related to continuity of the pay check ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, none of those are there.

It contains:
- any loans and mortgages you have and had, including loans you are not currently using (like credit cards, equity loans);
- all payments you made on any of those in time (or not);
- any bankruptcies and such;
- and any requests for credit you made (approved or not)

If they would want to know about any paychecks and employment history, they’ll have to ask you to provide such

Comment: thank you... apart from the listed details .. credit score will not have any other personal salary details .. !! good to know,very helpful !!